# How do you customize the wysihtml5 editor's background color, font, etc.?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wysihtml5, bootstrap-wysihtml5

I am using bootstrap-wysihtml5 in a website and need to customize the editor to match the look and feel of my website. For example, the bootstrap-wysihtml5 editor has a white background with black text, but I need to change it to, say, a red background with white text. I'd also like to use a different font.

If I use Fiddler to examine the `<iframe>` created by bootstrap-wysihtml5, I see that the `<body>` element in the `<iframe>` has the following `style` definition:

```
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
color: rgb(44, 62, 80); 
font-family: "Lato","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 
font-size: 15px; 
...
```

The `font-family` settings used here are defined in my `bootstrap.css` file, so I presume that's where the `style` definitions in the `<iframe>` are coming from, but I don't see how I can customize these to something different.

I've tried modifying the `<iframe>` `<body>` style via jQuery in the bootstrap-wysihtml5 `load` event, and that works, but as soon as I click on the editor the custom styling is overwritten with the default styling.

How do I implement my own custom styling in this editor?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own stylesheets to the iframe by setting an option when creating the wysihtml5 area:

```
$('#textarea-id').wysihtml5({
    stylesheets: ['/url/of/stylesheet/to/put/in/iframe']
});
```